# How do I move my primary domain out of the public_html folder?

Tags: domain

I'm new at this, but trying very hard, I hope you can help with this...

I recently asked my host to change my primary domain, which they did, and the previous primary domain is now "parked". As a consequence, my new primary domain, that I would like to use to create a brand new website, is displaying exactly the same content as the previous one.

Can anyone tell me what files I should move from the "public_html" folder and to what destination so I can finally free my new domain from the other one..?

Thanks

Comment: Are both domains hosted on the same server? (With WordPress?) Do you have access to the Apache or NGINX configuration yourself or is this something your host would set up for you? You probably need to set up [virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/) or similar. But I would try asking your host for help again.

Comment: If your question isn't specifically Wordpress realted, try https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/